# Amending code to copy formulas in hidden cells when creating a new line

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel to track results returned for a lab programme.  There are multiple users who use the spreadsheet and we have created custom views for each of them.  When they down load a new record they add a line using the VBA script below, which works great but there are some cells that need to be hidden from them that have formula in and need to copy down but don't.

Is there something I can add to this script to ensure formulas in hidden cells are also copied?

```
Sub New_Delta()

  ' Go to last cell
  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

  ' Copy formula from cell above
  Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
  Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

## A: copy last row ... simple version

If the last used row is ***completely*** visible, and the first column always contains anything, I suggest this:

```
Private Sub CopyLastRow()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or whatever sheet

    ' following two line are referred as "middle part" later
    Set r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    r.EntireRow.Copy r.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0) ' copy content and format

    Set r = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

If the last used row contains some empty cells somewhere, it might be better to determine the last used row by the (slower) `Range.Find` (exchange the middle part by following):

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) > 0 Then
    Set r = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    r.EntireRow.Copy r.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

## B: ... with hidden columns

Above also works, if you just have some "normal" hidden columns or grouped columns which are hidden.

## C: ... but last row is hidden by a filter

In such cases, both code variants above would find the last **visible** row and copy it to its next (=hidden) row by overwriting its content - of course unwanted!

If you change the middle part by following code, it works, if there is absolutely nothing below the last "used" row.
(for concerns about `UsedRange` see [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba))

```
Set r = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
r.EntireRow.Copy r.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0)
```

## D: ... but there are filtered rows *and* hidden columns

If you have filtered rows and additionally have hidden columns, either an error message about "multiple selection" raises or just the visible columns are copied and mess up.
I suggest to un-filter before.

## E ... but there are merged cells

Horizontally merged cells will be copied as is.

But if you have vertically (or vertically *and* horizontally) merged cells, they will be copied unmerged and contain nothing, as the content of merged cells is stored in the upper left cell (and therefore not copied, if the last row is copied):
[image: Screenshot with merged cells]

In this case you can copy the row and merge the cells:

```
Set r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
r.EntireRow.Copy r.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0) ' copy content and format

Dim c As Range
Dim CurrentColumn As Long
Dim MergedColumnCount As Long
For CurrentColumn = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set c = ws.Cells(r.Row, CurrentColumn)
    If c.MergeArea.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        MergedColumnCount = c.MergeArea.Columns.Count
        c.MergeArea.Resize(c.MergeArea.Rows.Count + 1, c.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Merge
        CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn + MergedColumnCount - 1
    End If
Next CurrentColumn
```

[image: Screenshot with re-merged cells]

As the border (maybe other formats also) of the merged cells may vary from the row above, you may restore it additionally.

Comment: `Set r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` should be faster (and shorter) than using `WorksheetFunction.CountA` with `Find`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, the code works perfectly when all the columns are unhidden but as soon as i try it in the custom view with hidden columns i get the following error:    **That command cannot be used on multiple selections**

Comment: I added some scenarios and explanations. It would help me, if you explain how you defined your "custom view". Do you have scenarion D?